# How to get insert id when using Android Room Insert AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room

how can I read insertId in the activity?
Activity:

```
private void saveNewCode() {
    mCodeRepository.insertCodeTask(mInitialCode);
}
```

in Repository InsertCode:

```
public void insertCodeTask(Code code) {
        new InsertAsyncTask(myDatabase.getCodeDao()).execute(code);
    }
```

InsertAsyncTask:

```
public class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Code, Void, Void> {
    private static final String TAG = "InsertAsyncTask";
    private CodeDao mCodeDao;
    private long insertId;


    public InsertAsyncTask(CodeDao dao) {
        mCodeDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Code... codes) {
        insertId = mCodeDao.insertCode(codes);
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I pass insertId to the Activity? implement interface or onPostExecute method, but how should it pass back to the Activity? Thanks.

Comment: Use a callback interface that the activity listens to and in your onPostExecute call the interface passing your id so the activity gets it

Comment: Could you explain it more?

Comment: Thanks @tyczj I made it.